# Integrating Skype with Mule

Tags: mule, skype

We have seen many example of integration of mule with Salesforce, Amazon, Facebook, LinkedIn. I have tried only LinkedIn and now since we don't have skype connector in mule. Using DataMapper i want to connect mule with Skype. I don't know where to start from.

Any Help or Hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone did start building a Skype Connector here: https://github.com/machaval/mule-skype-connector/

You will have to build this yourself using the DevKit. Plenty of info on getting started with the DevKit here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+DevKit